# How to get only end base file name in a directory structure using shell script(bash) or Linux command

Tags: shell, directory-structure

I have directory structure like this

- MainDIR/DIr2/b.txt
- MainDIR/DIr1/a.txt

I want to get only base file names, like a.txt and b.txt

Comment: What do you mean by "to get"? What shell? Do you perhaps mean `basename`?

Comment: yea, i need to get base file names

Answer (score 0):

To get the basename of a file path, which is stored in a shell variable `MYFILE`, you can do it like this:

In Zsh it is easiest, because you don't need to create a separate process:

```
$MYFILE:t
```

in bash (and, I think, ksh), the only method I know is

```
$(basename $MYFILE)
```

This works in Zsh too, but has the drawback that a sub-process is needed.

Comment: Thank you.
To list contents in a directory we usually use 'll MainDIR' which lists only DIr1 and DIr2. 
Is there any commands which list end files (base files) i.e a.txt and b.txt??

Comment: `ll` is not a Linux command. What exactly is it doing? And what you mean by "listing end files"? Getting only the basenames of the files somewhere in the directory hierachy? This would be `find MainDIR  -type f | xargs -n 1 basename`

Comment: Thank you, this was the one i was searching- 'find MainDIR -type f | xargs -n 1 basename'